# C code to find out if a number is "strong" or not ( literal translation from my language )

Tags: c

Right, we're currently learning loops in C.
The assignment is as follows ( literal translation ):

> "Strong numbers are those integers which can be written in a form of
>   a^2 b^3, where a and b are any integer. Examples of strong numbers:
>
> 1 = 1^2  1^3
>   4 = 2^2 1^3
>   8 = 1^2 2^3
>   32 = 2^2 2^3
>   675 = 5^2 3^3
>
> Ask the user one integer, and print out whether the number is strong
>   or not"

I'm completely lost here. Any help?

Comment: Please show some efforts first. If you have some code that you wrote and not working, please post it.

Comment: I suspect you meant `4 = 2^2 1^3`?

Comment: I have no idea how to tackle the subject, that's why I can't show any effort at all. If I had the idea on how to approach the subject; I'd be able to solve it without seeking help.

I guess I have to do something like a "for" loop checking x^2 * y^3 to see if anything matches with the number the user inputted, but as I said, I'm unsure whether that's the right approach.

And yes David, my bad there.

Comment: Well, since 1^3 = 1 (and 1^2 = 1), you can tell that the biggest value of a or b for N must be √N.  Therefore, in the worst case, you can loop over 1..√N for each of a and b and see whether they match.  You should be able to do better than that, though.

Comment: You can edit the question and should fix the typo David pointed out.

Comment: One approach would be to compute all possible strong numbers and then see if the user integer is one of those numbers.  I suspect this will be an easier solution than doing a prime factorization efficiently.  Have you been given an upper bound on the input integer? If it can go up to UINT64_MAX for example then this problem is getting hairy

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, you want to check to see if the exponent of each prime factor can be written as `2*a + 3*b` for integers `a` and `b`.  If so, the number is strong.  Otherwise it is not.

It's actually much simpler than it seems.  First, note that any integer > 1 can be written as `2*a + 3*b`, so you just need to see if any prime factors occur only once.

In terms of implementing it, you can do so even more simply by just examining and removing all factors starting at 2.

Here's an efficient implementation that won't overflow.  It returns 1 if `n` is strong and 0 if it isn't:

```
int is_strong(int n)
{
    int f, c;

    for (f = 2; f <= n/f; f++) {
        c = 0;
        while (n % f == 0) {
            n /= f;
            c++;
        }
        if (c == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return n == 1;
}
```

Note that I used `f <= n/f` rather than `f*f <= n` to avoid the risk of overflow (although that would be very unlikely).

Also note that this only works for integers >= 1.  You can add a special check for 0 if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with concept of [strong numbers](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_strong_number_n_Armstrong_number_in_C_language).
Anyways, for your problem, comments have the answers needed. You can try following:

1. Loop from 1 to root(N), store all prime factors of the given number. Then loop through the prime factors, checking all combinations of prime factors whether they satisfy the condition 'N = a^2b^3'. If none of them satisfies the condition, you can go on to combine prime factors into composite factors and then try each of them again. [This is one hell of a solution, probably the worst I can think of].
2. Loop from 1 to root(N), store all prime factors along with the number of occurrences of each prime factor. Loop through the list of prime factors, if number of occurrences of any of the prime factors is less then 2, say no else, yes. [This one is probably your solution].
3. You can alternately use a bottom up approach of dynamic programming to solve this question. Thats a longer answer and I think is irrelevant in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this one :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,s;
    long int n;

loop:
    while(scanf("%d",&n)&&(n!=0))
    {
        s=0;
        for(a=0;a<=100;a++)
            for(b=0;b<=100;b++)
            {
                if(a*a*b*b*b==n)
                {
                    printf("%d is strong numbers！\n",n);
                    goto loop;
                }
            }
        printf("not the strong numbers!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the integer 100 is the size,you can use this:#define SIZE 100 to decide the range of you want.

Comment: This is just an exhaustive search, with factors limited to 100 or less.  There are much more efficient solutions than this.  Also, why do you use `goto` instead of `continue`?  That's very bad style.

Comment: sorry,I think he just wants to learn about loops.I didn't care about effeciency.

Comment: Well, the real issue is this solution just doesn't work.  Try giving it 1024*1024 for instance.  You can't enumerate all possible factors like this.

Comment: I just cared about loops and result....

Comment: But it gives the wrong answers (results).

Comment: yes,the input must be a integer,or it can't recognize.so ,the code should be optimized much more.thank you for youe advice.

Answer (score 0):

Given `1^3` =1 and 1^2 =1

A strong number is strong

```
If it is square (9 = 3^2 . 1^3)

If it is cube (125 = 1^2 . 5^3)

If it's prime factors are in groups of 2 or more.
```

### Had a play and fixed algorithm

So generate prime factors.

Given a prime which is repeated n times. (e.g. 16 is factored to 2.2.2.2 => 2 has 4 occurnaces, n = 4).

If n == 1 then it can't be part of a cube factor, which would leave a single factor.
If n is odd, then a number of cubes need to be removed.

```
 CubeFactors = floor( n/3);
 if( CubeFactors %2 == 1 )
     CubeFactors -= 3;  /* We want to remove an odd number of factors, to ensure remaining factors are even (square).*/
 n =  n - CubeFactors * 3;
```

Then n is even, and thus representable as part of square.

Iterate through the counted prime factors.  If any have just 1 occurance it is not prime, otherwise for any other count, it is representable as a cube, a square or a combination of both.

```
a^2 => a^2
a^3 => a^3
a^4 => (a^2)^2
a^5 => a^3 . a^2
a^6 => (a^3)^2
a^7 => a^3 . (a^2)^2
a^8 => (a^4)^2
a^9 => (a^2)^3
a^10 => (a^5)^2
a^11 => (a^3)^3 . (a^2)
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work for 32, which is 2**5.